# ERROR: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNDocumentPicker' could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, hadoop-yarn

I've been receiving the below error in my React Native project:

> ERROR:  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNDocumentPicker' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes

This has started happening after including *import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker'* in my project (I installed the package using *yarn add react-native-document-picker*).  I've included my package.json content below:

```
{
  "name": "ezeap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.2.5",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "check-peer-dependencies": "^4.2.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "graphql": "15.8.0",
    "history": "5.3.0",
    "link": "^1.5.1",
    "ra-core": "4.11.3",
    "ra-data-graphql": "^4.10.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.3.0-next-fecc288b7-20221025",
    "react-hook-form": "7.45.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.7",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.13",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router": "6.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.13.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What are the steps that I should pursue to fix this?

The issue goes away when I remove the *import* statement pertaining to DocumentPicker.  Additionally, I've tried to remove and reinstall the *node_modules* folder, which unfortunately didn't solve the error.

Comment: Have you tried clearing caches and rebuilding? Probably the build doesn't have any native code from the new library

Comment: @Abe I tried running "yarn cache clean" and "yarn expo start -c"-- both failed to fix the error.

Comment: Update: I swapped from using the react-native-document-picker package to the expo-document-picker package (as my project uses Expo) and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use
"react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.1",
for now

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. My app was using expo and this solution worked for me

```
npm i react-native-document-picker
npx expo prebuild
npx expo run:android
```

The same can be done with ios.

This solution was taken from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/issues/655#issuecomment-1561279361)

For future reference,
Versions I was using:

```
 "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.0",
 "expo": "~49.0.15",
```

Comment: what if you're just trying to get it to work on web?